# How to find a function given parameters?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

A continuous function defined on $[-1,1]$ with $f(-1) = -1$ and $f(1) = 1$ such that $\left|f(x)\right |\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$

How can I find a function that fits this criteria?

Comment: @APCorreia undelete your answer, you were right, I overlooked the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

$f $ is continuous at $ [-1,1] $ and $ f(-1)f(1)<0$, So by IVT,

$$\exists c\in(-1,1) \;:\; |f(c)|=0<\frac 12$$

The function you look for cannot exist.